# Best practices for syncing DAGs in worker pods in Apache Airflow + Kubernetes

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have an Airflow deployment in Kubernetes configured with Kubernetes Executor. I setup a Git sync initContainer to fetch DAGs from my own DAGs repository, and I can see my Worker and Scheduler containers are running fine and have their DAGs folder updated with the latest commit. Thus, I wrote a simple DAG with two BashOperator but my worker pod, when scheduled, shows the following error:

```py
[2021-01-14 14:01:13,808] {dagbag.py:440} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /var/lib/airflow/dags/first_pod.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 40, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 48, in command
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 89, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/task_command.py", line 216, in task_run
    dag = get_dag(args.subdir, args.dag_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 187, in get_dag
    raise AirflowException(
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: dag_id could not be found: test. Either the dag did not exist or it failed to parse.
```

I understand my worker pod doesn't have any DAG. I would like to avoid to start a Git sync task every time a pod is spawned, so I would like to know if there are some best practices around for worker pod sync since I can't find any. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe put the dag's in a configmap and mount it this way?

Comment: I'm not sure this appropriately scales, i would like to avoid baked solutions. My desire is to push new dags in my repository and have my airflow deployment automatically pull changes at fixed rate so so that my system is kept in sync with my git repository. How can i maintain an updated ConfigMap?

Comment: DAG synchronization seems to be the hardest aspect for any of the executors. Will be interested to see if anyone has a clever idea. I'm not playing with airflow too much lately, but for a while I was using k8s Airflow and copying the DAG files directly into the Airflow image. But I agree the "baked" solution doesn't seem ideal.

Comment: @berrur ConfigMap is for storing configs including config files. DAGs are a type of config which determines how you run the tasks. So that's the best match. kubelets are in charge of the syncing of updated ConfigMap to the mounted files on all nodes. the update time is about every 1min. it is as scalable as you can get. Compare it to complicated solutions involving side-car containers and git-sync.